# VB and XML Encoding (UTF-8)?

Tags: xml

Guys...I really need your help..

I have this vb code where i will send a value typed in a textbox to MSMQ...

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim mq As MessageQueue
    'Dim format As XmlMessageFormatter
    Dim msg As Message
    'Dim dec As XmlDeclaration

    Try
        msg = New Message
        msg.Priority = MessagePriority.Normal

        If Not (MessageQueue.Exists(".\Private$\toNavision")) Then
            mq = MessageQueue.Create(".\Private$\toNavision")

        Else
            mq = New MessageQueue(".\Private$\toNavision")

        End If
        msg.Label = "Navision MSMQ-BA"
        msg.Body = TextBox1.Text

        mq.Send(msg)
        Label1.Text = "Message sent."

    Catch ex As MessageQueueException
        Label1.Text = ("MSMQ Error: " + ex.ToString())

    Catch ex As Exception
        Label2.Text = ("Error: " + ex.ToString())

    Finally
        mq.Close()

    End Try

End Sub
```

And the result is successful...where by I can see the message in the queue...but i'm not sure of the XML encoding...and i need to send the message in UTF-8, furthermore i can't figure out how to send those message to be UTF-8 into the Queue...

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Encoding can be altered with the use of the encoding-class.

```
Dim value As Encoding

value = Encoding.UTF8
```

More about using that with UFT8 can be read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx).